Как задать параметры функции в command?
Имеется кнопка, к которой нужно привязать функцию и передать в функцию параметр:
btn = Button(text="Простая кнопка", command=click(parameter="quit"))

при запуске код выше запустит функцию, но не привяжет функцию. Как задать параметры функции в command?

Можно воспользоваться lambda функцией:
btn = Button(text="Простая кнопка", command=lambda: click(parameter="quit"))
